# Subdivison surface awkward when extruding

Tags: subdivision-surface, extrude

Okay, I'll keep this question plain and simple.
Whenever I have cube use a subdivision surface and attempt to extrude vertices with that cube I get really awkward results because whenever it adds a vertex the model gets an awkward dent in it as seen below.

[image: Before extrude:]

[image: After extrude:]

As I once heard from a ten-year-old "Pls Help" And thanks in advance.
Here is the file:
[image]

Comment: you probably have a face inside your object, along the mirror axis, you must delete it

Comment: Nothing appears to be in the object.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your .blend using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: are you sure? because if you put a face along the mirror axis it gives exactly this result: https://zupimages.net/up/18/27/3dgj.jpg

Comment: Okay how could one remove this face.

Comment: on the bottom of your 3D view, click Face Select button, disable the Limit Selection to Visible button, you'll see the inside face, then select it and X > Delete Faces

Comment: Nope no faces are in the cube

Comment: Okay, I added the file so you could see it.

Comment: bad file, there is no problem with the file you've uploaded

Comment: What that doesn't make sense and its getting annoyed by us talking this way.

Comment: There is no crease in the file you uploaded.

Comment: Oh select the bottom and extrude it and then you'll see the issue.

Comment: You need to upload "your" file with "your" issue.

Comment: Oh, wait I FREAKING FORGOT TO ENABLE CLIPPING!!! I am officially an idiot.

Comment: it doesn't give the explanation, as I said you probably created an inner face. Plus you should put Mirror modifier above the Subsurface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you extruded, as you didn't activate the *Clipping* option of the Mirror modifier, you created a inner face on the mirror axis.

So you can either:

- Cancel your extrusion and redo it with the *Clipping* option enabled
- Or delete the inner face: On the bottom of your 3D view, click *Face Select* button, disable the *Limit Selection to Visible* button, you'll see the inside face, then select it and X > *Delete Faces*.

Also, you should put the Mirror modifier above the Subsurface modifier.