# Mirror modifier not working correctly

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to extrude using mirror modify and instead of connecting the mirrored section automatically, it creates two separate extruded sections. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112127/subdivison-surface-awkward-when-extruding/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subsurf splits the mirrored model into two objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46355/subsurf-splits-the-mirrored-model-into-two-objects)

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not wrong I think you mean the middle section where the mirror is?

It looks like you may have a face at that middle section. Just delete it and it will stick together instead of creating two separate sections

[image: Hidden face at the middle section]

There are hidden faces hidden in the middle section.

[image]

Press Z to select the face.

[image]

The Mirror Modifier automatically merges the vertices if the option to merge is turned on. No longer having a separate section.

Hope this helps! Enjoy your modeling ;)